# Oracle 11G XE alterar tamanho tablespace system

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g

Tenho seguinte script:

```
DECLARE
  countTablespaceFile integer;

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*)
  INTO countTablespaceFile
  FROM DBA_DATA_FILES
  where file_name in ('/oracle/bdond/cbiep01/bdrgt/system01.dbf',
                    '/oracle/bdond/cbiep01/bdsirr/system01.dbf',
                    '/tmp/system02.dbf',
                    '/tmp/system03.dbf');   

  -- Nas instâncias bdrst e bdpfrl, o tablespace não pode ser criado.
  -- bdrst -> já tem o '/tmp/system02.dbf'
  -- bdpfrl -> já tem o '/tmp/system03.dbf'
  IF countTablespaceFile < 1 THEN
     execute immediate 'ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM add datafile ''/tmp/system02.dbf'' size 4000m';
    END IF;
END;
```

e examente nessa linha tenho seguinte erro de tamanho do tablespace

> execute immediate 'ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM add datafile
>   ''/tmp/system02.dbf'' size 4000m';

relatório de erros:

> Relatório de erros - ORA-01119: erro ao criar o arquivo
>   '/tmp/system02.dbf' de banco de dados ORA-27040: erro ao criar
>   arquivo, não foi possível criar o arquivo OSD-04002: n��oss�l abrir
>   arquivo O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
>   ORA-06512: em line 17
>   01119. 00000 -  "error in creating database file '%s'"
>   *Cause:    Usually due to not having enough space on the device.
>   *Action:

Comment: Pergunta meio obvia.. mas tem espaço em disco para criar um novo datafile?

Comment: sim com certeza